# How the statements of R. El'azar Ben Azaria fits in the seder

Tags: passover-seder-hagada

What is the relevance of the [Mishna](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37939&st=&pgnum=73&hilite=) amar rabbi El'azar ben Azaria to the haggada? Why mention this machlokes and why here why now? How do we practically gain from this mention?