# אֲרַמִּי אוֹבֵד אָבִי not read entirely in the Hagadat Pesach

Tags: passover-seder-hagada, maseches-pesachim

The [Mishna 4 of the 10th Perek of Pesachim](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Pesachim.10.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) ends with "And he expounds from the passage (Sefaria):

> מַתְחִיל בִּגְנוּת וּמְסַיֵּם בְּשֶׁבַח, וְדוֹרֵשׁ מֵאֲרַמִּי אוֹבֵד אָבִי, עַד שֶׁיִּגְמֹר כֹּל הַפָּרָשָׁה כֻלָּהּ
>
> "An Aramean tried to destroy my father” (Deuteronomy 26:5) until he concludes explaining the entire section."

Seems like on a surface level, we would need to read the entire section of אֲרַמִּי אוֹבֵד אָבִי which is Parshat bikkurim, but in the Hagadah of Pesach we don't read Parshat Bikkurim entirely. Why is it?

Comment: How much do you want us to read?

Comment: @DoubleAA, when the Mishna says the entire section, what do YOU understand?

Comment: It says *until he finishes explaining* Thus we have the explanation after the words of that section, not just reading the words.

Comment: Maybe a dupe?..

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70544/why-is-the-section-of-%d7%90%d7%a8%d7%9e%d7%99-%d7%90%d7%95%d7%91%d7%93-%d7%90%d7%91%d7%99-chosen-as-the-main-part-of-maggid-in-the-sed/70563#70563

Answer (score 0):

some meforshim say….

it means

until you finish the whole
parsha that pertains to “arame
oivaid avi”